# passing variables to cloud-config chef?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, cloud-init, user-data

I'm trying to create a user-data script with cloud-init using the chef features. I've run into a limitation and I'm wondering if there's a way around it. I need my node names to be unique since the chef server will only accept a client with a unique name. I've tried several things to pass either a datetime variable or the instance ID, but I can't seem to pass variables to the node_name section.

```
node_name: "server-app-$INSTANCE_ID"
```

or

```
node_name: "server-app-$(date +%s)"
```

Is there a way to escape this so that it doesn't get interpreted literally?

```
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "server-app-$INSTANCE_ID"
```

Comment: Are you using a cloud-config script? The documentation states that the "node_name" will default to the instance-id. That should be unique. See: http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#install-and-run-chef-recipes

Comment: I understand that, but I'm trying to keep some kind of naming scheme in the node name for monitoring purposes. If I could somehow prepend the instance ID with the naming scheme, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do the expansion before you write out the `client.rb`:

```
echo "node_name '$(date +%s)' >> /etc/chef/client.rb"
```

Not that this could still collide if two machines boot in the same second. I would highly recommend using the EC2 instance ID or IP address instead. You can fetch these from the metadata server. See https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/packer/client-bootstrap.sh#L26-L37 for an example.

Comment: what you propose would work for a user-data shell script, but I'm trying to write a cloud-config yaml file. If I specify a node name directly to the client.rb file, won't that get overwritten by the cloud-config setting?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with cloud-config (assuming you mean the coreos thing), but you can use `write_files` if you don't want to just run a script.